# Spark: Run Spark shell from a different directory than where Spark is installed on slaves and master

Tags: cluster-computing, apache-spark

I have a small cluster (4 machines) set up with 3 slaves and a master node, all installed to `/home/spark/spark`. (I.e, `$SPARK_HOME` is `/home/spark/spark`)

When I use the spark shell: `/home/spark/spark/bin/pyspark --master spark://192.168.0.11:7077` everything works fine. However I'd like for my colleagues to be able to connect to the cluster from a local instance of spark on their machine installed in whatever directory they wish.

Currently if somebody has spark installed in say `/home/user12/spark` and run `/home/user12/spark/bin/pyspark --master spark://192.168.0.11:7077` the spark shell will connect to the master without problems but fails with an error when I try to run code:

```
    class java.io.IOException: Cannot run program 
    "/home/user12/bin/compute-classpath.sh"
    (in directory "."): error=2, No such file or directory)
```

The problem here is that Spark is looking for the spark installation in **/home/user12/spark/**, where as I'd like to just tell spark to look in **/home/spark/spark/** instead.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to edit three files, `spark-submit`, `spark-class` and `pyspark` (all in the `bin` folder).

Find the line

```
export SPARK_HOME = [...]
```

Then change it to

```
SPARK_HOME = [...]
```

Finally make sure you set `SPARK_HOME` to the directory where spark is installed on the cluster.

This works for me.

Here you can find a detailed explanation.

http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/executor-failed-cannot-find-compute-classpath-sh-td859.html